# How do I log properly a Laravel Job?

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-8, laravel-jobs

Reading the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging) I understand that it's necessary to use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log`, but the configuration in `logging.php` is a bit confusing to me. I basically don't understand how the channel drivers work, it seems to me a bit overcomplicated.

Logging commands, however, is pretty easy in my opinion: you just add `->appendOutputTo('command.log')` in the schedule method and the job is pretty much done. Is there a similar method to log jobs? Or is the way in the documentation the only one? If so, could anyone be kind enough to simplify it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple to use the Log facade,

Go to `loggin.php` and add a new channel, here is a signle log file example (without rotation)

```
'job' =>  [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/job.log'),
            'level' => 'info',
        ],
```

Then use it anywhere with

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

Log::channel('job')->info($content);
//or
Log::channel('job')->error($content);
```